# How to replace a number of character with a single one?

Tags: ubuntu, replace, sed, tr

If the character is met more than once I must replace it with a single one. For example i have this in a file: `????aca`, I must replace it with `?aca`. I've tried it with `tr`, but didn't make it to work proper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems easy with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) using backreferences:

```
sed 's/\(.\)\1\+/\1/g' infile
```

Comment: Thanks, but this command is replacing all the characters that are met more than once, but I need to replace only "?", I didn't mention this proper.

Comment: @user3091715: then replace `.` with `?` (or `\?` if for your regexp it's a special character)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to truncate consecutive runs of one particular character, `tr -s` does that.

```
tr -s '?' <file >file.new
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your limitation to `?`

```
sed 's/[?]\{2,\}/?/g' YourFile
```

also POSIX compliant